# Re-balance Portfolio Over Time

Tags: python-3.x

I have a big challenge with the implementation of a `rebalance portfolio` function. I don't understand very well my goal and I confirm that my implementation does not work, and I'm looking for ways to fix it.

```
def rebalance_portfolio(returns, index_weights, shift_size, chunk_size):
    assert returns.index.equals(index_weights.index)
    assert returns.columns.equals(index_weights.columns)
    assert shift_size > 0
    assert chunk_size >= 0

    m = returns.values.shape[0]
    cov = get_covariance_returns(returns)
    x = cvx.Variable(m)
    portfolio_variance = cvx.quad_form(x, cov)
    print(portfolio_variance)    
    distance_to_index = cvx.norm(x - index_weights)
    objective = cvx.Minimize(portfolio_variance + shift_size * distance_to_index)
    x_values = get_optimal_weights(returns, index_weights, shift_size)

    return x_values
```

Note that:

```
returns is a DataFrame. Returns for each ticker and date.
index_weights is a DataFrame. Index weight for each ticker and date.
shift_size is an integer. The number of days between each rebalance.
chunk_size is an integer. The number of days to look in the past for rebalancing.
```

In my implementation, I must use two functions. Firstly, `get_covariance_returns(returns: DataFrame) return 2 dimensional Ndarray The covariance of the returns`. This function returns the covariance calculation of a DataFrame `returns`. Secondly, `get_optimal_weights(covariance_returns:2 dimensional Ndarray, index_weights:Pandas Series, scale=2.0) return 1 dimensional Ndarray`. This function find the optimal weights.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Does your function presently work, and you would like to optimise it, or does it need fixing?

Comment: I got you, thanks! My function does not work I would like to fix it or propose an example that could guide me to understand what I must do.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the same course from Udacity right now, and I have found a working answer given in this link for your question "http://digtime.cn/articles/126/ai-for-tradingproject3smart-beta-and-portfolio-optimization-46".

The code is as below:

```
all_rebalance_weights = []

   for i in range(chunk_size, len(returns), shift_size):
       chunks = returns.iloc[i - chunk_size:i]
        
       cov_returns = get_covariance_returns(chunks)
      
       opt_weights = get_optimal_weights(cov_returns, index_weights.iloc[i-1])
        
       all_rebalance_weights.append(opt_weights)

   return all_rebalance_weights
```